# Camera Sensitivity in PointerLockControls to match actual games

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a FPS game online. I want the user to be able to use a sensitivity they are familiar with from games they've played. In this case, I want them to use their Fortnite sensitivity.

I am trying to figure out the Math behind it all.

I have figured out how to change the sensitivity in the PointerLockerControls.js file and can edit it from my main js file.

```
this.speedFactorX = 0.002;
this.speedFactorY = 0.002;

euler.y -= movementX * scope.speedFactorX;
euler.x -= movementY * scope.speedFactorY;
```

I want to know what type of unit the '0.002' is.

In fortnite, I have my sensitivity at '0.08'. Obviously, this is way too fast to replace the speed factor values.

What kind of math do I need to match the users sensitivity in fortnite, to the speed factor values?

Hope someone can understand what I mean. Thanks!

This may help with the fortnite values - https://jscalc.io/calc/RTCJTLMts42GYfWf

I will be using the fortnite slider.

Comment: Three.js' euler angles are calculated in radians. Maybe Fortnite is using degrees? I'm thinking 0.002 radians is 0.11 degrees, which is close to 0.08. Either way, the folks at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might have a more educated answer for you.

Comment: Thanks! Will ask the question over there aswell.